# Selecting struct type columns with '.' in the column name in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How do I select the `"cat.item.category"` columns in PySpark? The schema is as follows,

```
root
 |-- result: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- active: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- cat_item.category: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- display_value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- link: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- number: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- sys_id: string (nullable = true)
```

I tried the following but I get an error,

```
df22 = df22.select("result.active", "result.cat_item.category.display_value", "result.cat_item.category.link", "result.number", "result.sys_id")
```

How do I select the struct columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field name contains a dot `.`, you need to escape it using backtick **`**:

```
df22.select("result.`cat_item.category`.display_value")
```